# Understand a result of FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

```
FullSimplify[((Sqrt[5] - 1)/(2*2^(1/4)))*Sqrt[Sqrt[2]*5^(1/4) - Sqrt[Sqrt[5] - 1]]]
```

returns

```
(-13 + 6*Sqrt[5] - 2*Sqrt[85 - 38*Sqrt[5]])^(1/4)
```

What are the steps to show this identity?

Edit: The work of FullSimplify here is just collecting all factors under the square root and multiplying out. But the difficult way is backwards: How to see that the result can be written as a product with a factor

```
(Sqrt[5] - 1)^2
```

Comment: `RootReduce` may be helpful, I think.

Comment: Honestly, whatever method *Mathematica* is using under the hood is not likely to be easily done by hand, so I question the desire to ask *Mathematica* for a step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a step by step solution using WolframAlpha. For this you type == at the beginning of a cell. Then you type your expression and hit Return. In the result, there is a button labeled "Step-by-step solution".

It looks like:

[image]

Comment: The Step-by-Step solution consists of rationalizing the denominator and is not really helpful

Comment: I do not think you can get more info. `FullSimplify` is built with efficiency in mind and not with an educational purpose.